# Problem creating pic-viewer with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning the basics of JavaScript in a course at school. This because I want to have a big understanding of JavaScript when I'm diving into different libraries.

I've successfully managed to create a function who spawn a `<div>` that is hidden with a picture within it (I've cheated with "the pure" JavaScript with the fadeIn function as you see).

The problem now is that i want the function to be dynamic and work for more than just one element. I don't now how to proceed with this problem.

Any help or thoughts will be appreciated.

```
    <div id="hiddenElement">
        <img src="#" alt="image" class="maxImg"/>
    </div>

    var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('hiddenElement');
    anchor.addEventListener('click', spawnImage, false);


    function spawnImage() {
            $(hiddenElement).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                hiddenElement.style.display = 'block';
            });
```

looks like this now:
http://oscarlandstrom.se/javascript/pic.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to unify this function?Then you can pass div and back ids as function parametrs:

```
function spawnImage(divId, backId) {
            $(divId).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'block';
            });
            $(backId).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                document.getElementById('backId').style.display = 'block';
            });
```

When you load page call something like that:

```
spawnImage(fistDivId, backId);
spawnImage(secondDivId, backId);
```

Comment: Im spawning the image with a eventListener. And I want it to work for more than just one element.

      addEventListener('click', spawnImage, false);

Answer (score 0):

So you can set class="spawn" for all elements you want your function hold. (class="spawn" - it is empty class used just to mark elements). Then you should set on load event like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var spawnedElamants = getElementsByClassName("spawn");
  for(var i=0; i<spawnedElamants.length; i++)
  {
    spawnImage(spawnedElamants[i].id, backId);
  }
});
```

Comment: I will try to make this work. Otherwise i will come back with further questions. Thanks for the help and the fast response :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css" />
        <script src="js.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bkgFade"></div>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="imgWrap">
                <img src="http://www.morrharet.se/images/morrharet.jpg" alt="image" id="anchor" class="minImg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="imgWrap">
                <img src="http://www.morrharet.se/images/morrharet.jpg" alt="image" id="anchor2" class="minImg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hiddenElement">
            <img src="http://www.morrharet.se/images/morrharet.jpg" alt="image" class="maxImg"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var minImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("minImg");
        var maxImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("maxImg");
        var bkgFade = document.getElementById('bkgFade');
        for(var i=0; i<minImgs.length; i++)
        {
            minImgs[i].addEventListener('click', spawnImage, false);    
        }
        for(var i=0; i<maxImgs.length; i++)
        {
            maxImgs.addEventListener('click', despawnImage, false);
        }
        }
    )

    function spawnImage() {
        $(hiddenElement).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            hiddenElement.style.display = 'block';
        });

        $(bkgFade).fadeIn('slow', function() {  
            bkgFade.style.display = 'block';

        });
    }

    function despawnImage() {
        $(hiddenElement).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            document.getElementById('hiddenElement').style.display = 'none';
        });
        $(bkgFade).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            document.getElementById('bkgFade').style.display = 'none';

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I have different images, how do I put them in hiddenElement by best practice ?

Comment: can in someway put in the maxImgs into hiddenElement ?

Comment: As "hiddenElement" - div is hidden it is no matter how you put images in it.
`<div id="hiddenElement">
<img src="fist.gif" alt="image" class="maxImg"/>
<img src="second.gif" alt="image" class="maxImg"/>
</div>`. For all images with class "maxImg" will be set click listener - despawnImage.